# Problems with the Z-values / exporting MXD (ArcMap) to DXF (AutoCAD)

Tags: arcmap, export, dxf, mxd, z-value

Circular arcs are polygonalized in the DXF output. Several support points are inserted into an arc, which are connected to each other with polylines. The Z-values ​​of the inserted support points are interpolated.

It has been noticed that not only the inserted support points have an interpolated height (Z-values), but all support points of the object have an interpolated Z-value. In the course of this, the Z-values ​​of the points from the ArcMap Data are also overwritten.

Is it possible to transfer the data without interpolation? Just with the fixed Z-values. Or another way to fix the data?

Comment: How exactly would a "fill" work when the "from" and "to" vertices have different Z values?

Comment: Hi!

Meanwhile, I work around the problem by inserting additional vertices and changing the segment to straight. The Interpolation works fine and the values ​​are displayed correctly.

Does anyone know of a tool that does this automatically?